# How would one achieve superscript references with the multibbl package?

Tags: bibliographies

I am using multibbl to manage separate bibliographies, and prefer to use superscript citations.  However, multibbl clashes with cite (a little) and other packages: natbib biblatex (much worse).

```
\documentclass{book}

% Bibliography
\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite}     % Citation management
\usepackage{multibbl}

\newbibliography{lit}
\newbibliography{gen}

\begin{document}

Some point.\cite{lit}{pem1976}

\nocite{gen}{ha}{*}

\bibliographystyle{lit}{plain}
\bibliography{lit}{ch4biblit}{Literature}

\bibliographystyle{gen}{plain}
\bibliography{gen}{ch4bibgen}{General}

\end{document}
```

In this example, cite prevents citations from being passed to the lit.aux file.  Funny enough, \nocite works fine.  When the cite package is commented out, citations pass correctly to the aux, but the formatting is obviously lost.

What is the easiest solution?

Comment: I would say the easiest is to use bibatex alone, since it is relatively easy to customise the formatting of citations/bibliographies.